# Get request with Access and Secret Key

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am a newbie to Python. I am trying to write a Python script to get some JSON data. The Linux shell command is as below and it works perfectly when fired form shell:-

```
curl -H "X-ApiKeys: accessKey={accessKey}; secretKey={secretKey}" https://example.com/example/api/v1/example/list
```

Below is the Python script as far as I have reached till now and got stuck and absolutely no idea what to do next.

```
import requests
import ConfigParser
import json
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read('C:/Users/admin/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject/config.ini')
Username = Config.get('credentials',  'Username')
Password = Config.get('credentials', 'Password')
```

Comment: Forget to mention, the response list will be in json format.

Comment: Can you tell me the API you are trying to use so I can test?

Comment: @skagra_dragneel I am trying to hit Tenable API..The link is https://cloud.tenable.com/container-security/api/v1/container/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't have a login for the API, but the general program should look like this

```
import requests
import ConfigParser
import json

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('C:/Users/admin/source/repos/MyProject/MyProject/config.ini')
username = config.get('credentials',  'Username')
password = config.get('credentials', 'Password')

request_url = 'example_url'
headers = {'X-ApiKeys' : 'accessKey=' + username + '; secretKey=' + password}

print requests.get(request_url,headers=headers).json()
```

I changed the variables declared to be lowercase just to follow python conventions. Keys are generally put in the header of the request which is a dictionary in python's requests library. If that doesn't work, feel free to include the error and I will try to make my answer work.

Comment: It worked !!! Just added a + before 'password'.. Thank You Very Much.. Now I am proceeding with learning how to parse this json data and send that in email.. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Kalim You're welcome, if you have any other questions feel free to ask

Comment: I was able to hit api and parse json for particular value. There are multiple value for id, but I was able to get only one value. My Print statement is "print get_response[0]['id']". How can I get both or all of the values for id ?

Comment: @Kalim send me the full api response and I can can what I can do

Comment: Here is the output. I have truncated few key/value :-

[{u'name': u'centos', u'created_at': u'2018-03-08T10:03:36.965Z', u'updated_at': u'2018-03-12T05:21:48.676Z', u'platform': u'Docker', u'score': u'0.0', u'number_of_vulnerabilities': u'0', u'id': u'5414863959740255895', u'repo_name': u'kalimrepo2'}, {u'name': u'kalimrepo', u'created_at': u'2018-03-08T09:56:16.554Z', u'updated_at': u'2018-03-12T04:47:42.732Z', u'platform': u'Docker', u'score': u'6.0', u'number_of_vulnerabilities': u'18', u'id': u'-7650316543982955793', u'repo_name': u'kalimrepo'}]

Comment: @Kalim ids = []
for item in get_response:
    ids.append(item['id']) will get you a list of ids

Comment: Thanks... It worked like a charm.. Thank you very much.